# Xamarin iOS Storyboard in Library project

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard

I have added Storyboard file in Library project and using this library in my main project.
I am getting issue while creating an instance of a controller.

> var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("SomeStoryboard", null);
>     var controller = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SomeController");
>     var someController = controller as SomeController;

I am getting 'null' value for 'someController' in a 3rd line.

Do we have any other way for getting instance of a controller from Library project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with your code if everything is setting properly. I wrote a demo and it works on my side.

Make sure that you have set the correct **SomeController** in the `SomeStoryboard`, here is a screenshot:

[image]

I uploaded a test project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/iOS-library) and you can check, feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: Thanks for a reply Jack. Yes Jack, I will try and let you know that. Presently, I had dropped that idea and created .XIB files and that worked.

Comment: Ok, XIB file should be same as storyboard. If it works, you can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).